# Change TFS 2015 commit time zone

Tags: git, tfs, timezone, tfs-2015

I've a quick TFS 2015 Git question : I'm in the EST time zone (-5) so when I commit something locally and push it to the remote (TFS), all commits are dated with the proper time zone (-0500) in my git log :

```
commit 3fbf0c4b4e4a2bf91b251af44a7d92bca9aaf606
Author: ************* <**********@*************>
Date:   Tue Nov 8 09:13:28 2016 -0500

    Revert C4, C3, C2
```

However, if the commit as been done using the TFS web editor, the commit is in the wrong timezone (+0500) :

```
commit 7d2dbcb08a580439047ea68061c7883f3c8b3ec4
Author: ************* <**********@*************>
Date:   Wed Nov 9 19:43:44 2016 +0500

    Updated Index.html
```

The time zone is correct on :

- My local machine
- The server hosting my TFS application tier (see image below)
- In my profile (see image below)

Is there another place where I can set the time zone ? I could understand the the time zone would be the server time zone or UTC but +5, I've no idea where it comes from.

Thanks

**Server time zone setting**

[image]

**Profile screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Make sure you restart the TFS server after change the server time zone.

Comment: I didn't change it (it was already correct)

Answer (score 0):

The web portal time zone should be the same with IIS server time zone (the **TFS server system time zone**). If you want to change the web commit time zone, you just need to change the time zone of your TFS server. (Need to be restart)

After this the **new commit will change to new time zone**, however the old record will still in the old time zone, just as below picture: *(Also make sense, the log has been recorded)*

[image]

---

If you just  want to show the log with your local time zone. You can try to use   `git log --date=local` command to print the commit log. This will **return the info with local time zone.**

Or using below command with `%cd` (commit date) to  **optimize your display mode**, this will also return your local time zone.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h-%an, %ar  %cd "
```

Comment: When you talk about changing the TFS server time zone, you mean the general time zone of the server (which is already correct, see question update) or another time zone setting specific to IIS and/or TFS ?

Comment: This may be the old record of the log, after the changing of time zone, Did you restart TFS server and create a new commit to see if the log of new commit have changed to the corresponding time zone.

Comment: I know I can use a command to display the commit date/time in the local time zone, I was just wondering why is has been committed in the wrong time zone from my server. Not a huge deal, just a bit weird.

Comment: **The git commit time zone  with sever should be correct with your TFS time  zone.** There must be some thing wrong with the synchronous, Since you have not change the sever time zone. Suggest you to change it to UTC, and restart TFS server.90 Then create a new commit to see if the log shows the correct time zone(UTC not +5 OR -5). If it works, then change the time zone of your TFS sever back to  original.

Answer (score 0):

Login to tfs through web, hover on the DP icon in top right corner (left to 3 dots)

Click on My Profile

Choose LOCALE

Choose the time zone of your choice

Comment: If you look at the original question, it's already been tried.